# Приостановка или воспроизведение видео в Chrome на C# или Python

Tags: python, c#, google-chrome

Мне нужно эмулировать нажатие пробела, чтобы приостановить или воспроизвести видео в Chrome. Я пытался эмулировать нажатие пробела в Python, это работает, но как ввод пробела, ничего больше.

'''

```
import pyautogui

pyautogui.keyDown('SPACE')
```

'''

```
pyautogui.press('playpause');
```

Comment: use media keys, luke

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow in Russian! As the name implies, Russian is the working language of this site. Please either translate your question into Russian or [ask the same question on StackOverflow in English](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Your question may be closed soon, but it will most likely be reopened if you choose to translate it.

Comment: Вопрос закрыт, так как на Stack Overflow на русском вопросы принято задавать только на русском языке. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или воспользуйтесь Stack Overflow на английском

Answer (score 0):

```
pyautogui.press('space');
```

Нашел как это сделать